# How to add a temporary column for sql query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a SQL query for summary my table:

```
    $this->where('kriteria =', 'fakir');
    $this->where('zona !=', '0');
    $this->select('surveyor,zona,kriteria,area');
    $this->selectCount('surveyor', 'count');
    $this->selectSum('nilai', 'nilai');
    $this->groupBy('surveyor');
    $this->groupBy('kriteria');
    $this->groupBy('area');
    $this->orderBy('kriteria', 'ASC');
    $this->orderBy('zona', 'ASC');
    $this->orderBy('count', 'DESC');
```

Output:

| surveyor | zona | kriteria | area | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RT06 RW07 | 1 | FAKIR | RUNGKUT | 125 |
| RT08 RW07 | 1 | FAKIR | RUNGKUT | 78 |

I need to take only 1 data from the query result but I can't use surveyor cause it contain space. I plan to add maybe like id for identify data that i need but I don't know how, I use codeigniter 4.4.3

I've tried call the id but it refer to only one single data from before query

Answer (score 0):

To convert this into a complete SQL query, it would look something like this:

```
SELECT surveyor, zona, kriteria, area, COUNT(surveyor) AS count, SUM(nilai) AS nilai
FROM your_table
WHERE kriteria = 'fakir' AND zona != '0'
GROUP BY surveyor, kriteria, area
ORDER BY kriteria ASC, zona ASC, count DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this->where('kriteria', 'fakir');
$this->where('zona !=', '0');
$this->select('surveyor, zona, kriteria, area');
$this->selectCount('surveyor', 'count');
$this->selectSum('nilai', 'nilai');
$this->select("CONCAT(surveyor, '_', zona, '_', kriteria, '_', area) as custom_id", false);
$this->groupBy('surveyor');
$this->groupBy('kriteria');
$this->groupBy('area');
$this->orderBy('kriteria', 'ASC');
$this->orderBy('zona', 'ASC');
$this->orderBy('count', 'DESC');

$queryResult = $this->get()->getResult();

$selectedRow = null;

foreach ($queryResult as $row) {
    if (strpos($row->custom_id, 'desired_value') !== false) {
        $selectedRow = $row;
        break;
    }
}

This example uses the CONCAT function to concatenate the values of surveyor, zona, kriteria, and area with underscores to create a custom_id for each row. You can adjust the concatenation logic based on your requirements. In the loop, you can then use any logic to select the desired row based on this custom_id or other criteria.
```